# How to combine multiple rows into one row in big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have table which has the following data:

```
bank | user  | chqno | chqdated    | Amount |
ban1 | user1 | 11111 | 12.12.2017  | 200    |
ban1 | user1 | 11111 | 12.12.2017  | 300    |
ban1 | user2 | 22332 | 12.12.2017  | 300    |
```

For output I want to get something like this:

```
bank | user  | chqno | chqdated    | Amount |           
ban1 | user1 | 11111 | 12.12.2017  | 500    |
ban1 | user2 | 22332 | 12.12.2017  | 300    |
```

I tried some queries, but the data keeps repeating without adding properly. Any suggestions, how to handle this issue?

Comment: Please show what did you do

Comment: where the branch comes from!? and why legacy-sql as a tag? are you still there?

Comment: where the 22332  for chqno comes from?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Sorry, That was part of data that's not relevant. I forgot to remove it.

Comment: more generic/important question  - what is the logic exactly for the grouping? just input and output examples are not always enough to reverse-engineer the logic - so please spell it out :o)

Comment: When I look for data for a user on a particular date, I want it all added together and show 1 date only one time. Right now, it is showing the same date multiple times. I tried to get sum and group it by the date but it added the amount but kept showing it multiple time.

Comment: still  - can you clarify where 22332 came from in the input/output example you provided in your question.

Comment: @VSR - did you have chance to try my answer? it should do exactly what you asked - even after you just updated your question

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, I did try the solution but still the data is not combined based on dates.

Comment: I think the answer provided by Milhail Beryant gives exactly what asked for, if that is not working for you, you should probably edit your question, and explain how do you want to combined based on dates.

Comment: @VSR -  just wanted to follow up on your update - it does not change the answer as the question anyway was read that way based on actual question and not based on initial title. :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 'ban1' bank, 'user1' user, '11111' chqno, '12.12.2017' chqdated, 200 Amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ban1', 'user1', '11111', '12.12.2017', 300 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ban1', 'user2', '22332', '12.12.2017', 300 
)
SELECT bank, user, chqno, chqdated, SUM(Amount) Amount
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
GROUP BY bank, user, chqno, chqdated
```

with result as

```sql
Row bank    user    chqno   chqdated    Amount   
1   ban1    user1   11111   12.12.2017  500  
2   ban1    user2   22332   12.12.2017  300
```

Comment: I feel like the answer actually answers your exact question  - and I am glad Xiaoxia Lin confirmed this too. Please revisit it again